# Eclipse Android design view of res/values/strings.xml not working anymore

Tags: android, eclipse

This was working fine when I first started the project.  I am referring to editing/adding to the strings.xml file.  It used to display a design and XML tab that allowed me to update it.  now its just showing up as a table.  Any ideas?  I don't understand how I could have messed this up.  I did check in another project of mine and I am getting the same results so I don't think it has anything to do with the XML.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What if you right-click the .xml file and specify the editor you're opening it with?

Comment: Nice!  If I right click, open with, then select Resource Editor, I'm in!  Thank you!  Now, how do I award you the answer?

Comment: @EboMike - if you add your response as an answer I'll select it to make sure that you get credit.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just right-click the XML file, that way, you can specify which editor to open it with. That'll do the trick! It should also remember your last choice, so the next time you double-click it, it should use that editor.